# Get Latitude and Longitude data from all Firebase documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
how can i get the latitude and longitude data of all my documents from a collection in firebase

the document name is the uid of the user;

I was thinking that I need to make a query for get the data I need.

How can I Do it?

I am trying something like this:

FIREBASE STRUCTURE:

```
collection:
  Providers
    docs:
      23ejb32be32e32 - (uid)
        data:
          address: {
            latitude: -23.322,
            longitude: -22.222
          }
```

```
async function getProviderLocation() {
      try {
        const db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection('Providers')
          .where('latitude', 'array-contains', 'latitude')
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.empty) {
              console.log('nao tem');
              return;
            }

            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          });

        const document = await db
          .collection('Providers')
          .doc('lVXWjScexiuNlZaXAon4')
          .get();

        if (document.exists) {
          setPoints([
            ...points,
            {
              latitude: document.data().address.latitude,
              longitude: document.data().address.longitude,
            },
          ]);
        } else {
          console.log('doc não existe');
        }
```

Can Anyone help me please???

Comment: What specific line in the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
I need to get the data from the documents of a collection (Providers)

but the name of the documents is the user's uid.

how can I do this?

Comment: Without seeing the actual data in the document, and knowing exactly what you want out of it, it's hard to say what you should do.  Please edit the question to show the data you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson 
I updated my question with a small structure of my firebase, tell me if this is enough

Comment: @DougStevenson I added an Image of the struture too, latitude and longitude will be within address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't match the document structure in your screenshot. Since there is no array field called `latitude`, the query returns no documents.

Your screenshot shows a document that has a `address` field that is a map. That `address` map/field has subfields for `longitude` and `latitude`.

To print all `map.longitude` and `map.latitude` values, you'd do:

```
db.collection('Providers')
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('nao tem');
      return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data().address.longitude+" - "+doc.data().address.latitude);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```